# How to run strace with specific file descriptor?

Tags: linux, strace

I am trying to use `strace` to sniff unix domain socket.

I run a process having multiple file descriptors, some file descriptors would call `recvmsg` system call. But I just want to sniff only specific file descriptor like 1 and run command below:

```
strace -e trace=recvmsg -p 27366 -e recvmsg=1
```

But `strace` showed this error. How can I solve this problem?

```
strace: invalid system call 'recvmsg=1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-e read=fd` instead of `-e recvmsg=fd`.

`recvmsg` is a kind of `read`.

Example:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>
int main(void){
        char buf[512]; int fd[2];
        struct iovec iov = { buf, sizeof buf };
        struct msghdr msg = { .msg_iov = &iov, .msg_iovlen = 1 };
        if(socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0, fd)) err(1, "socketpair");
        write(fd[0], "foo\n", 4);
        recvmsg(fd[1], &msg, 0);
}
$ cc -s -Wall foo.c -o foo
$ strace -e trace=recvmsg -e read=all ./foo
recvmsg(4, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="foo\n", iov_len=512}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 4
 * 4 bytes in buffer 0
 | 00000  66 6f 6f 0a                                       foo.             |
+++ exited with 0 +++
```